# How to disable esc key in html page using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to disable the ESC key in an HTML page. How can I do this?

I have a form which is appearing as jQuery UI Dialog. Here if I click the ESC key, the form will close. I want to disable that.

Comment: The esc key generally does nothing on a web page. Please explain what do you mean by disabling it

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I have a form which is appearing as Dialog. Here if i click esc key, form will close. I want to disable that.

Comment: How is the dialog created? jQuery? You will probably want to disable this functionality in the dialog, not the whole page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Browsers ([Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_navigation), [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en)...) normally bind the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to the "stop loading current page" action. Any other behaviour needs to be specifically coded with JavaScript.

The jQuery UI Dialog has a [closeOnEscape](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-closeOnEscape) setting. Just set it to `false`:

- Initialize a dialog with the closeOnEscape option specified:

  ```
  $( ".selector" ).dialog({ closeOnEscape: false });
  ```
- Get or set the closeOnEscape option, after init:

  ```
  //getter
  var closeOnEscape = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "closeOnEscape" );
  //setter
  $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "closeOnEscape", false );
  ```

Comment: @KingRider - It's hard to believe that jQuery UI Dialogue has a [documented property](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-closeOnEscape) that doesn't work at all. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @alvaroVicario - Try trigger jquery? http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ and javascript pure is http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp ... to result is return false before make alert a message Test!

Comment: @KingRider Pardon? Are you comments related to this precise **jQuery UI Dialog** question?

Comment: @alvaroVicario - only a example scripts ur knowledge.

Comment: This was driving me nuts because I wanted to catch esc myself and do something with it, and I could not figure out what was getting there first.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) return false;
});
```

*thanks Johan

Comment: This will work if focus is on any input elements like text area etc.

But if focus is on blank area, this will not work.

Comment: This answer is correct given the original question; it is working just fine. The reason it "will not work" is because the actual issue you are having is that the third-party dialog app you want to prevent using the Esc key is registering its own key event on a subelement of `document`.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is to figure out which dialog library you are using (colorbox? jquery ui? shadowbox) and disable the `esc` key (for example, in [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) you can set the `escKey` option to false).