# Disable ESC behavior on Firefox 2.0 browser with jquery

Tags: jquery, firefox, firefox2

Browsers like Firefox use the ESC key to stop loading the current page, stopping any request on curse.

I need to stop this behavior.

I need to stop/disable the browser behavior and replace it for another set of actions I need to execute on ESC key press.

I have found some solutions in jquery but what I get is the ESC key stop working at all, I have to use the ESC key, I can not change that.

I have to use Firefox 2.0

Any ideas?

Comment: Too many "I need", not enough question

Comment: Share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable esc key in html page using javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729249/how-to-disable-esc-key-in-html-page-using-javascript-or-jquery)